# compute a certain maximum in MATLAB

Tags: optimization, matlab

let $ C \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ c_1>c_2>\ldots>c_k \in \mathbb{N} $ with $ C>c_1 $ and $ c=(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k)^\top \in \mathbb{N}^k $, where $ \mathbb{N} $ are the natural numbers without zero. Consider the set
$ A:= \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{N}_0^k \, \middle| \, c^\top x \ge C, x \mbox{ has } (P) \right\rbrace $, where $ (P) $ is the following property:
$ \forall \, i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,k \rbrace \, : \, x_i \ge 1 \Longrightarrow c^\top \left(x-e^i\right)<C $ with $ e^i $ as the $i$-th unit vector.

How can I compute in MATLAB-Code 
$ f^\star=\max \left\lbrace c^\top x \, \middle| \, x \in A \right\rbrace $?

Comment: Did you mean to use $m$ instead of $k$? Also what is $\mathbb{N}^m_0$? And where does the if-then constraint come from? I feel there might be a better way to formulate the problem given more info on the background.

Comment: I corrected the mistakes concerning $ m $ and $ k $. $ \mathbb{N} $ stands for the natural numbers, i.e., they start with $ 1,2,3,...$ and $ \mathbb{N}_0 $ contains additionally zero. The problem is related to a covering problem. One would like to cover the distance $ C $ using as many as necessary objects with lenghts $ c_1>c_2>\ldots>c_k $. The aim is, to find the longest cover, where no object is redundant, i.e. if we get rid of a single object, the total distance becomes smaller than $ C $.

Comment: Do you need to solve an optimization problem for this? Assuming $\sum_{i} c_i \geq C$, then You can simply iteratively compute $\sum_{i=1}^N c_i$ until the summation becomes larger than C. I think you can prove that using the largest possible numbers from the list c_i will be optimal in this case (because of the redundancy requirement). Can you try to show this? If not I'll give it a go and post as an answer.

Comment: I think, this does not lead to the optimal value. Consider the case $ C=10 $ with $ c_1=6 $, $ c_2=4 $, $ c_3=3 $ and $ c_4=2 $. Then your approach leads to $ f^\star=c_1+c_2=10 $ but we have $ f^\star\ge c_1+c_3+c_4=11 $. Additionally you have to consider that due to the definition of the set $ A $ these lenghts $ c_i $ can be taken several times, i.e. $ c_2+c_2+c_2=12 $ is also a valid combination. Thus we have $ f^\star \ge 12 $.